# Scanner problem Dell V305W

Tags: windows-xp

Unable to scan a color photo with the dell V305W. It will scan black and white. It only scans 99% when I try to scan color. It says the parameter if incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reinstall the drivers for the scanner? If possible, try another application...

You can check if the scanner itself has a defect by trying the scanner on another PC.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the scan resolution to a lower setting. Also some scanners need to be associated with an image software like MS Paint, because it will open the scanned image when it is done scanning so you can see it, look in the toolbox software and set the association.

Click ® Programs.

Click Dell Printers.

Click Dell V305.

Select Dell Imaging Toolbox.

The Dell Imaging Toolbox dialog box opens.

From the Home screen, click Scan.

The What are you scanning? dialog box opens.

Click Custom Settings.

From the Scan Resolution drop down menu, select a lower scan resolution.

To make this setting the default for all scan jobs, select Always use these settings when scanning.

Click Start to start scanning, or click Preview to preview your document or photo before scanning.